# Angular momentum of anyons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, spin-statistics, anyons

Why is it true that [anyons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyons) can have angular momentum taking any real value? Why aren't they restricted to the $j(j+1)$  integer values most are familar with?

Answer (score 1):

Starting in a 3 dimensional space, any path where one particle traces a closed loop around another can be trivially contracted to a point where no motion occurred.  This then means that the wavefunction before and after the motion must be the same and so the wavefunction can only be multiplied by a phase of $e^{i2\pi n}$ where $n$ is an integer.  In 2 dimensions, however, the closed path around another particle cannot be contracted to a point.  Thus, the wavefunction does not need to return to its original form and may be multiplied by a phase of the form $e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta$ is a real number.

More detail is available in the book [Anyons by Jon Magne Leinaas](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-70626-7_5#).